# Where condition on extra field many to many with Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I would like to know how can I execute a where condition on extra field.

Currently I have 3 tables :

```
Courses : id, title, description,
Sections: id, title, description,
CoursesSections : id, fk_course_id, fk_section_id, position
```

Currently I have this request and It works to have Course with Sections associate order by position :

```
let course = await db.Course.findOne({
    where: {
        id: parent.dataValues.id,
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: db.Section,
            as: "Section",
            through: {
                attributes: ["position"],
            },
        },
    ],
    order: [[Sequelize.literal("position"), "ASC"]],
})
```

But I would like to apply a where condition, to have only position 1, or 2 for example.

I tried this, but it doesn't work :

```
course = await db.Course.findOne({
    where: {
        id: 1,
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: db.Section,
            as: "Section",
            through: {
                attributes: ["position"],
            },
            where: {
                position: 2,
            },
        },
    ],
    order: [[Sequelize.literal("position"), "ASC"]],
})
```

I have this error :

> "message": "Unknown column 'Section.position' in 'on clause'"

Answer (score 0):

I put the where condition in through :

```
const course = await db.Course.findOne({
    where: {
        id: parent.dataValues.id,
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: db.Section,
            as: "Section",
            through: {
                attributes: ["position"],
                where: {
                    position: 1,
                },
            },
        },
    ],
    order: [[Sequelize.literal("position"), "ASC"]],
})
```